Trino query to select data from hive table not returning any rows
I have an Azure Data Lake Storage Account with the following simple structure.
<storage_account>/hive/test/test.csv
test.csv contains the following data:
name,age
john,10

I run the following Trino commands to create a schema and table pointing to this directory:
trino> create schema hive.test with (location='abfss://hive@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/test');                                                                                           
CREATE SCHEMA

trino> use hive.test;                                                                                                                                                                            
USE                                                                                                                                                                                              
trino:test> create table test (name varchar, age varchar) with (external_location='abfss://hive@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/test', format='CSV', skip_header_line_count=1);                
CREATE TABLE

trino:test> select * from test;                                                                                                                                                                  
 name | age                                                                                                                                                                                      
------+-----                                                                                                                                                                                     
(0 rows)

Why are there no results returned?
If I do an INSERT:
trino:test> insert into test(name, age) values ('bob', '20');                                                                                                                                    
INSERT: 1 row                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                
Query 20240525_070814_00043_f73s5, FINISHED, 2 nodes                                                                                                                                             
Splits: 22 total, 22 done (100.00%)                                                                                                                                                              
2.09 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

I can see a new CSV file is uploaded to the storage account path as expected, but still no results when doing a select * from test;
My hive connector is configured in Trino as follows:
  hive: |
    connector.name=hive
    hive.metastore.uri=thrift://<metastore>:<port>
    hive.compression-codec=NONE
    hive.security=allow-all
    hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled=true
    fs.native-azure.enabled=true
    azure.auth-type=ACCESS_KEY
    azure.access-key=<my_access_key>

Trino version 448. Hive metastore version 3.1.3.
